# Inverse Matrix operation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

We know that for matrix multiplication in general $AB\neq BA$.

But if $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix, with $|A|\neq0$.
How to prove that if
$A^{-1}A=I_n$, then
$AA^{-1}=I_n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For example, in this way.

Let a matrix $B$ be chosen such that $AB=I$. Then $(A^{-1}A)B=A^{-1}(AB)$. Hence $IB=A^{-1}I$. So $B=A^{-1}$.

2. You can also reason like this.

Since $\operatorname{det}(A)\neq0$,
the rows of the matrix $A$ are linearly independent.
This means that from $(y_1,\ldots,y_n)A=0$
it follows that $(y_1,\ldots,y_n)=0$
and if $Y$ $n\times n$-matrix,
then from $YA=0$ it follows that $Y=0$.

Now let $A^{-1}A=I$.
Then $A(A^{-1}A)=A$ and $(AA^{-1})A=A$.

So $(AA^{-1}-I)A=0$.
From the above, it now follows that $AA^{-1}-I=0$ or $AA^{-1}=I$.

Comment: This answer only shows that **if** there exists some matrix $B$ such that $AB=I$, then $B=A^{-1}$. In other words, it is an incomplete answer.

Comment: Yeah this assumes that B always exists.

Comment: @5xum Without assuming the existence of $B$ or some similar assumption, we can't prove our claim. There are monoids which have an inverse on the left but no inverse on the right, so we cannot talk about commutativity.

Comment: @kabenyuk But we are not in monoids. We are speaking about regular old matrices.

Comment: @5xum I just wanted to say that besides equality $A^{-1}A=I$ we must use something else (I took advantage of the existence of the right inverse). Using only this equality and associativity of multiplication, the equality $A^{-1}A=AA^{-1}$ cannot be derived.

Comment: But you didn't have to use anything else. One can just use the properties of matrices. You don't need to assume the existence of a right inverse. Not with matrices.

Comment: @5xum can you give the simplest answer that you are talking about without assuming this

Comment: @MDHossain I added another version of reasoning to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The map $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ given by $f(x) = Ax$ is a bijection: if $f(x) = f(y)$ then $Ax = Ay$ and so $x = y$ since $A$ has a left inverse, so $f$ is injective. Hence by the rank nullity theorem $f$ is also surjective, and so $f$ has a unique set theoretic inverse $g$, which satisfies $f \circ g = g \circ f$. We know that $h(x) = A^{-1}x$ is a left inverse for $f$, since $g$ is both a left an right inverse,
$$
h  = h \circ (f \circ g) = (h \circ f) \circ g = g.
$$
That is, $AA^{-1} = A^{-1}A = I$.

Answer (score -1):

From $AA^{-1}= B$ and given that $A^{-1}A= I$ we can write $A(A^{-1}A)A^{-1}= B$.

So $(AA^{-1})(AA^{-1})= I(I)= I= B$

Comment: I think this shows that $B^2 = B$, might need some more justification to then conclude that $B = I$. For example, why isn't $B = 0$?

Comment: When you say "So $(AA^{-1})(AA^{-1}) = I(I)$", where does that equality come from?

Comment: Why $AA^{-1}=I $that is the question

Comment: user2271513: No, it does not give B^2= B, it gives B= 1.  5xum: We start with the hypothesis that AA^{-1}= 1.  Therefore (AA^{-1})(AA^{-1})= I(I).  MD Hossain- Yes, I got A and A^{-1} reversed.  So just swap them in what I wrote.

Comment: @user247327 Well, starting with a hypothesis that $AA^{-1}=I$ is not ok, because that is what you want to **prove**. What you **should** start with is the hypothesis that $A^{-1}A=I$, and from that, prove that $AA^{-1}=I$.